# Geonetwork Authentication from an API client

Tags: geonetwork, react

I'm working on developing a client application that can push metadata to Geonetwork using Reactjs and [Geonetowork API](http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/doc/api/). To be more specific, I'm trying to add a record with the API `/{portal}/api/0.1/records`. My question is how to I can authenticate my request. I tried the Basic Authentication but I'm getting `(403 Forbidden)`.
Sample of my request:

```
  let basicAuth = 'Basic ' + btoa("username" + ":" + "password");
  axios.put("/geonetwork/srv/api/0.1/records?metadataType=SUB_TEMPLATE", this.state.xml, {
    headers: {
      accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
      'Authorization': + basicAuth
    },
  })
```